# Read child elements from xml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, xml-parsing

I have a xml file where the image url, description and its category is stored. In my view, I have a dropdown list which is also pulled out from the "category name" of the xml file  and now I need to display the image of selected category. I've been following couple examples [Populate dropdown list in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112567/populate-dropdown-list-in-mvc) and http://forums.asp.net/t/1580460.aspx/1. I got the dropdown list part working but stuck getting the image url and the desctiption.

Here is my xml file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<SymbolOption>
  <Category id="1" name="categoryA">
      <image url="A.png" desc="image a"/>
      <image url="B.png" desc="image b"/>
      <image url="C.png" desc="image c"/>      
  </Category>
  <Category id="2" name="categoryB">
      <image url="x.png" desc="image x"/>
      <image url="y.png" desc="image y"/>      
  </Category>
</SymbolOption>
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var imageFile = Server.MapPath("~/Data/ImageSource.xml");
            var category =
                from symbolCategory in XDocument.Load(imageFile).Descendants("Category")
                select new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = symbolCategory.Attribute("id").Value,
                    Text = symbolCategory.Attribute("name").Value
                };
            var model = new SymbolCategoryViewModel
            {
                Categories = category
            };
            return View(model);            
        }
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
public class SymbolCategoryViewModel
{
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Category, Model.Categories)

<div id="displayImage">
    <img  src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/" + URLfromXML)">
    @Html.DisplayFor(image description)
<div>
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did solve your problem, but it is not the best solution, since you did not specify how you would like it to be done.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<MySelectListItem> category =
          (from symbolCategory in XDocument.Load("d:\\data.xml").Descendants("Category")
           select new MySelectListItem
           {
               Value = symbolCategory.Attribute("id").Value,
               Text = symbolCategory.Attribute("name").Value,
               Images = GetImgUrl(symbolCategory.Descendants("image"))
           }).ToList();
        return View(category);
    }

    private List<ImageUrl> GetImgUrl(IEnumerable<XElement> list)
    {
        List<ImageUrl> retVal = new List<ImageUrl>();
        foreach (XElement el in list)
        {
            ImageUrl url = new ImageUrl();
            url.Description = el.Attribute("desc").Value;
            url.Url = el.Attribute("url").Value;
            retVal.Add(url);
        }
        return retVal;
    }
```

Model

```
    public class MySelectListItem
{
    public string Value { set; get; }
    public string Text { set; get; }
    public List<ImageUrl> Images { set; get; }
}
public class ImageUrl
{
    public string Url { set; get; }
    public string Description { set; get; }
}
```

View

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
@model List<MySelectListItem>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var images = [];
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <text>images["@item.Value"] = 
            [
            @{int i=0;}

                @foreach(var img in item.Images){
                <text>{url : "@img.Url",desc:"@img.Description"},</text>
                i++;

        }]
        </text>
        }


        function changeImgs(obj) {
            var img = images[obj.value];
            var divImg = document.getElementById("images");
            divImg.innerHTML = "";
            var html = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
                html += img[i].desc + "<br />" + "<img src='" + img[i].url + "' /><br/>";
            }
            divImg.innerHTML = html;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <select onchange="changeImgs(this)">
        @foreach(var item in Model)
        {
            <option   value="@item.Value">@item.Text</option>

        }
    </select>
    <div id="images">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks, how do I get the Image description and the url in view

Comment: But for one category you have many images. Do you want just the first one? And for which category? The selected one? You will have to do some javascript coding.

Comment: I want to display the all the images of that category. Yes I want to display the images of selected category.

Thanks